# Acer Aspire One - Console Opens on Boot "Unable to open Display ' :0.0'

Tags: bash, console, acer-aspire

My mother just gave me her Laptop (Acer Aspire One ZG5) and showed me the following:

[image]

I tried to change the hostname, which should be a solution for this problem, but I've noticed that I havent got any kind of root password.
Rebooting the device doesnt change anything either.
Hopefully you can help me out! - Thank you already

I apologise if I did anything wrong in setting up this question, I've just joined this forum.

Greets,
Tobias H.